# How to draw angled corners for gradients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not entirely sure how to title this but, I'm trying to write a function in Unity for creating a gradient border image, and I can get the first edge of the gradient to draw the angle but, I can't figure out how to make it work otherwise.

Current Result:

[image]

Intended Result:

[image]

My current Code:

```
public static Texture2D CreateBorder ( this Gradient gradient, int width, int height, int borderSize ) {
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D ( width, height );

    // Create Base
    for(int y=0;y<height;y++) {
        for(int x=0;x<width;x++) {
            texture.SetPixel ( x, y, gradient.Evaluate ( 1f ) );
        }
    }

    // Create Bottom
    for ( int y = 0; y < borderSize; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = borderSize; x < ( width - borderSize ); x++ ) {
            float t = (float) y / borderSize;
            texture.SetPixel ( x, y, gradient.Evaluate ( t ) );
        }
    }

    // Create Left
    for ( int y = borderSize; y < ( height - borderSize ); y++ ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < borderSize; x++ ) {
            float t = (float) x / borderSize;
            texture.SetPixel ( x, y, gradient.Evaluate ( t ) );
        }
    }

    // Create Top
    for ( int y = height-borderSize; y < height; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = borderSize; x < (width-borderSize); x++ ) {
            float t = (float) (height-y) / borderSize;
            texture.SetPixel ( x, y, gradient.Evaluate ( t ) );
        }
    }

    // Create Right
    for ( int y = borderSize; y < (height-borderSize); y++ ) {
        for ( int x = (width-borderSize); x < width; x++ ) {
            float t = (float) ( width - x ) / borderSize;
            texture.SetPixel ( x, y, gradient.Evaluate ( t ) );
        }
    }

    texture.Apply ();
    return texture;
}
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to make the corners meet without overriding each other.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be the most efficient but it works so...

```
public static Texture2D CreateBorder ( this Gradient gradient, int width, int height, int borderSize ) {
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D ( width, height );

    // Create Gradient
    for ( int i = 0; i < borderSize; i++ ) {
        for ( int y = i; y < height - i; y++ ) {
            for ( int x = i; x < width - i; x++ ) {
                float t = (float) i / borderSize;
                texture.SetPixel ( x, y, gradient.Evaluate ( t ) );
            }
        }
    }

    // Create Background
    for ( int y = borderSize; y < height - borderSize; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = borderSize; x < width - borderSize; x++ ) {
            texture.SetPixel ( x, y, Color.clear );
        }
    }

    texture.Apply ();
    return texture;
}
```